# How can i use two progressBar controls to display each file download progress and also overall progress of all the files download?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace SatelliteImages
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int count = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ExtractImages ei = new ExtractImages();
            ei.Init();
        }

        private async Task DownloadFile(string url)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                int nextIndex = Interlocked.Increment(ref count);

                await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, @"C:\Temp\TestingSatelliteImagesDownload\" + nextIndex + ".jpg");
            }
        }

        private async Task DownloadFiles(IEnumerable<string> urlList)
        {
            foreach (var url in urlList)
            {
                await DownloadFile(url);
            }
        }

        private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await DownloadFiles(ExtractImages.imagesUrls);
        }
    }
}
```

imagesUrls is List

This code is working but i want now to add two progressBars the first one will show the overall progress the second one will show each file download progress.

I have already in the designer progressBar1 and progressBar2

But not sure how to use them with the async Task and the await.

What i tried so far:

Added a DownloadProgressChanged event handler:

```
private async Task DownloadFile(string url)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                int nextIndex = Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressCallback);
                await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, @"C:\Temp\TestingSatelliteImagesDownload\" + nextIndex + ".jpg");

            }
        }
```

I added the line:

```
client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressCallback);
```

Then in the event:

```
private void DownloadProgressCallback(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
```

But it's never get to 100% per file download. Each time it's downloading the progressBar is getting to another percentages but never to 100%.

Comment: I suggest using [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `async/await` for this specific case.

Comment: And the question is....

Comment: You will need to implement the event handler for DownloadProgressChanged: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3  to get progress on the download.   As for the total files to download, you need a counter and just update the second progressbar

Comment: @Sorceri i tried but the progressBar that show the download progress of each file never get to 100% it's getting to some percentages each time but never to the end of the progressBar. sometimes it's downloading a files getting to 1/3 of the progressBar some less never to the the end on the right side ( 100% ).

Comment: @Sorceri Updated my question with what i tried.

Comment: @MosesMeteor please see my edit for an example in case you are interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`IProgress<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and [`Progress<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

```
async Task SomeAsynMethod(IProgress<double> progress)
{
    double percentCompletedSoFar = 0;
    while (!completed)
    {
        // your code here to do something

        if (progress != null)
        {
            prgoress.Report(percentCompletedSoFar);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how to use it in the calling code:

```
async Task SomeAsyncRoutine()
{
    var progress = new Progress<double>();
    progress.ProgressChanged += (sender, args) => 
    {
        // Update your progress bar and do whatever else you need
    };

    await SomeAsynMethod(progress);
}
```

**Example**

To run the following example, create a windows form application and add one `Label` named `label1`, one `ProgressBar` named `progressBar` and one `Button` named `button1`. In a real scenario, you would give your controls more meaningful names. Replace all of the code in your form with this code.

What this simple application does is:

When you press the button, it deletes "Progress.txt" file if it exists. It then calls `SomeAsyncRoutine`. This routine creates an instance of `Progress<double>` which implements `IProgress<double>` interface. It subscribes to the `ProgressChanged` event. It then calls `SomeAsyncMethod(progress)` passing the instance `progress` to it. When the progress is reported, it updates the `progressBar1.Value` and it updates the `label1.Text` property.

The `SomeAsyncMethod` mimics some work. Using a loop starting at 1 and finishing at 100, it writes the loop variable (progress) to a file, sleeps for 100ms and then does the next iteration.

The progress to a file in the bin folder named "Progress.txt". Obviously in a real application you will do some meaningful work.

I kept the method names in the application the same as in the snippet I provided so it is easily mapped.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        File.Delete("Progress.txt");
        await SomeAsyncRoutine();
    }

    async Task SomeAsynMethod(IProgress<double> progress)
    {
        double percentCompletedSoFar = 0;
        bool completed = false;
        while (!completed)
        {
            // your code here to do something
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                percentCompletedSoFar = i;
                var t = new Task(() => WriteToProgressFile(i));
                t.Start();
                await t;
                if (progress != null)
                {
                    progress.Report(percentCompletedSoFar);
                }
                completed = i == 100;
            }
        }
    }

    private void WriteToProgressFile(int i)
    {
        File.AppendAllLines("Progress.txt",
                    new[] { string.Format("Completed: {0}%", i.ToString()) });
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    async Task SomeAsyncRoutine()
    {
        var progress = new Progress<double>();
        progress.ProgressChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // Update your progress bar and do whatever else you need
            this.progressBar1.Value = (int) args;
            this.label1.Text = args.ToString();
            if (args == 100)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Done");
            }
        };

        await SomeAsynMethod(progress);
    }
}
```