# Why using backgroundworker is not working good and sometimes i'm getting exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

In the form1 i'm starting the backgroundworker after i'm creating the List imagesUrls in another class.

But what i'm getting in the dowork event and then in progresschanged event is on the progressBar1 and also on the label2 i see it's counting by 10's: 10,20,30,40....100% then when it's getting to 100% it throw exception.

The exception:

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

The exception is in the Program.cs on the line:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

What i want is to download each file from the List imagesUrls and to update the progressBar and the label2 on each file download progress from 0% to 100% by 1's not 10's: 1,2,3,4,5...100 each file download to report progress of the download from 0 to 100

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace SatelliteImages
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ExtractImages ei = new ExtractImages();
            ei.Init();

            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            for (int i = 1; i <= ExtractImages.imagesUrls.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    using (var client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        client.DownloadFile(ExtractImages.imagesUrls[i], @"C:\Temp\TestingSatelliteImagesDownload\" + i + ".jpg");
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                        worker.ReportProgress(i * 10);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            label2.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Then i have the class i create the List imagesUrls:
When i'm running the program sometimes i'm getting exception not all the time.

The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)
       at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(String address)
       at SatelliteImages.ExtractImages.ExtractDateAndTime(String baseAddress) in D:\C-Sharp\SatelliteImages\SatelliteImages\SatelliteImages\ExtractImages.cs:line 97
       at SatelliteImages.ExtractImages.Init() in D:\C-Sharp\SatelliteImages\SatelliteImages\SatelliteImages\ExtractImages.cs:line 30
       at SatelliteImages.Form1..ctor() in D:\C-Sharp\SatelliteImages\SatelliteImages\SatelliteImages\Form1.cs:line 26
       at SatelliteImages.Program.Main() in D:\C-Sharp\SatelliteImages\SatelliteImages\SatelliteImages\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

And the class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace SatelliteImages
{
    class ExtractImages
    {
        static WebClient client;
        static string htmltoextract;
        public static List<string> countriescodes = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> countriesnames = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> DatesAndTimes = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> imagesUrls = new List<string>();
        static string firstUrlPart = "http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=";
        static string secondUrlPart = "&time=";
        static string thirdUrlPart = "&ir=";

        public void Init()
        {
            ExtractCountires();
            foreach (string cc in countriescodes)
            {
                ExtractDateAndTime("http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=" + cc);
            }
            ImagesLinks();
        }

        public static void ExtractCountires()
        {
            try
            {
                htmltoextract = "http://sat24.com/en/?ir=true";//"http://sat24.com/en/";// + regions;
                client = new WebClient();
                client.DownloadFile(htmltoextract, @"c:\temp\sat24.html");
                client.Dispose();

                string tag1 = "<li><a href=\"/en/";
                string tag2 = "</a></li>";

                string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\sat24.html");
                s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(tag1));
                s = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(tag2) + tag2.ToCharArray().Length);
                s = s.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace(" ", "");

                string[] parts = s.Split(new string[] { tag1, tag2 }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


                string tag3 = "<li><ahref=\"/en/";

                for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 17)
                    {
                        //break;
                    }
                    string l = "";
                    if (parts[i].Contains(tag3))
                        l = parts[i].Replace(tag3, "");

                    string z1 = l.Substring(0, l.IndexOf('"'));
                    if (z1.Contains("</ul></li><liclass="))
                    {
                        z1 = z1.Replace("</ul></li><liclass=", "af");
                    }
                    countriescodes.Add(z1);
                    countriescodes.GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1);

                    string z2 = parts[i].Substring(parts[i].LastIndexOf('>') + 1);
                    if (z2.Contains("&amp;"))
                    {
                        z2 = z2.Replace("&amp;", " & ");
                    }
                    countriesnames.Add(z2);
                    countriesnames.GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }

        public static void ExtractDateAndTime(string baseAddress)
        {
            var wc = new WebClient();
            wc.BaseAddress = baseAddress;
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

            var temp = wc.DownloadData("/en");
            doc.Load(new MemoryStream(temp));

            var secTokenScript = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                .Where(e =>
                       String.Compare(e.Name, "script", true) == 0 &&
                       String.Compare(e.ParentNode.Name, "div", true) == 0 &&
                       e.InnerText.Length > 0 &&
                       e.InnerText.Trim().StartsWith("var region")
                      ).FirstOrDefault().InnerText;
            var securityToken = secTokenScript;
            securityToken = securityToken.Substring(0, securityToken.IndexOf("arrayImageTimes.push"));
            securityToken = secTokenScript.Substring(securityToken.Length).Replace("arrayImageTimes.push('", "").Replace("')", "");
            var dates = securityToken.Trim().Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var scriptDates = dates.Select(x => new ScriptDate { DateString = x });
            foreach (var date in scriptDates)
            {
                DatesAndTimes.Add(date.DateString);
            }
        }

        public class ScriptDate
        {
            public string DateString { get; set; }
            public int Year
            {
                get
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(this.DateString.Substring(0, 4));
                }
            }
            public int Month
            {
                get
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(this.DateString.Substring(4, 2));
                }
            }
            public int Day
            {
                get
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(this.DateString.Substring(6, 2));
                }
            }
            public int Hours
            {
                get
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(this.DateString.Substring(8, 2));
                }
            }
            public int Minutes
            {
                get
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(this.DateString.Substring(10, 2));
                }
            }
        }

        public void ImagesLinks()
        {
            int cnt = 0;
            foreach (string countryCode in countriescodes)
            {
                cnt++;
                for (; cnt < DatesAndTimes.Count(); cnt++)
                {
                    string imageUrl = firstUrlPart + countryCode + secondUrlPart + DatesAndTimes[cnt] + thirdUrlPart + "true";
                    imagesUrls.Add(imageUrl);
                    if (cnt % 10 == 0) break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

About the class:

1. How should i handle the exception ? I want in general to handle by trying the operation again since i will make an update of the list imagesUrls each X time i want that if there is exception try the operation again and not to stop.
2. How can i use the class with the backgroundworker in form1 too ? So when it's first downloading in the class all the files there it will display the progress of the downloads also on form1 progressBar1 and label2.

But first to fix the problems in form1 code then to handle also the class.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370300/how-can-i-use-two-progressbar-controls-to-display-each-file-download-progress-an/41370508#41370508) regarding progress bar. I have also provided a detailed example to help you with it.

Comment: Do you have logs from the server (or some way of getting more details)? Error 500 is pretty generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your progress problem: There is a mistake with your line `worker.ReportProgress(i * 10);`.
`i` can range from `0` to `ExtractImages.imagesUrls.Count()`. So as soon as i is greater than 10, your are reporting a progress over 100%. So you are going over your progress bar range (if you check the content of the exception, you should probably have an Inner Exception = ArgumentException on the Progress Bar value).

Replace with `worker.ReportProgress(Math.Floor(100*i/ExtractImages.imagesUrls.Count()));` and make sure your progress bar max value is 100.

For the second problem, can you identify which line generates the error? As it is an Error500, the problem on server side. Unless you have access to the server logs to identify the source, you'll have to handle it with a try/catch block, and manage the problematic entries (I think simply ignoring them, and warn the user that some entries have a problem is a reasonable first approach).